# External closed workbook, table reference return error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to solve this issue without success.

I have a Excel workbook1 with a named table, let's call it TABLE.

In another workbook2 I need to use a formula referencing this table as follows:

=SUM('C:\Users\Documents\Workbook1.xlsx'!TABLE[Total])

As you can see I am using the field Total in TABLE to Sum. The problem is that when the workbook1 is closed I get a #REF!. When it is open the formula works fine.

I have searched for solutions and found that this is a limitation of using tables but I wonder whether is there a way around it.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Excel you have you could probably use the "Get External Data" under the data tab. You could also use the "New Query" option. I am using Excel 2013 with office 365 so your options might be different. I am not sure what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Hi, I am using 2016 version but I want to see if there is a way to make the formula work as the users of the spreadsheet could have a older version, let's say 2010, 2007...

Comment: It can be tough to make worksheets backwards compatible. Off the top of my head I would say that the source workbook would have to be in a public location like a share drive folder and then they would have to open "connections" under the  data tab and then "open source". That will open the file for them and then it should update. If you are familiar with VBA you could write a script that does it. Then you could just assign a hot key. That would do all the work for you and would be the most consistent solution.